# Image Hover using Cascading Style Sheets

Tags: css, image, hover

I want to swap an image on hover using CSS... I cannot figure out what I've done wrong.

```
a.dropbox_banner_link:link {
        width: 520px; 
        height: 70px;
        background: url('/images/RESD/SendArtwork-Button-Full-Colour_sm.png'); 
}

a.dropbox_banner_link:visited {
         width: 520px; 
        height: 70px;
        background: url('/images/RESD/SendArtwork-Button-Full-Colour_sm.png') no-   repeat;   
}

a.dropbox_banner_link:hover {
        width: 520px; 
        height: 70px;
        background: url('/images/RESD/SendArtwork-Button-Grey_sm.png') no-repeat;  
}

a.dropbox_banner_link:active {
        width: 520px; 
        height: 70px;
        background: url('/images/RESD/SendArtwork-Button-Grey_sm.png') no-repeat; 
}
```

The Website is www.signsinthemaking.com. and the images folder is in the root. The Referring CSS is:

```
<a href=" ?page_id=" class="dropbox_banner_link"></a>
```

I had it working before but at some point saved over the CSS Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you simply forgotten to make your links displaying as blocks:

```
.dropbox_banner_link {
    width: 520px;
    height: 70px;
    display: block;
    background: url('/images/RESD/SendArtwork-Button-Full-Colour_sm.png');
}
```

As they're `inline` by default, and they don't have any content, they're rendered as 0px/0px elements. That's why you don't see them.

Comment: Thank you... It was driving me crazy... I further short formed it to have the link/visited and hover/active together

Answer (score 1):

On hover you only need to update the values you want to change so in this case it would be the background image specifically and also by default `a` is an inline element.

So sort of like this

```
<a class="sample_hover"></a>

.sample_hover {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-image: url("https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png");
}

.sample_hover:hover {
    background-image: url("https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo9w.png");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you don't need to declare styles for every state of a link. You want only change the background on hover. So, it will be enough work only with styling hover state, because everything else is without changes.

Make sense to use ***background-image*** and ***background-repeat*** properties for easier overriding styles.

Also, need to declare ***a*** element like a block element (by default it is an inline element). You can read about this here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

```
a.dropbox_banner_link {
    display: block; 
    width: 520px; 
    height: 70px;
    background-image: url('/images/RESD/SendArtwork-Button-Full-Colour_sm.png'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

a.dropbox_banner_link:hover {
    background-image: url('/images/RESD/SendArtwork-Button-Grey_sm.png');  
}
```